# 5V UPS design IC/ battery-backup circuit selection

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, ups

Im trying to do an UPS for a new proyect with a li-ion battery like cellphones ones, it needs to be reliable as I would like to left it at home without surveillance.
I have found this: [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/36938/141659) from and old post. [image]

I would like to know if this works now a days, as the Post is 4 years old now, Mosfet life cycle is in "end of life" so maybe can be replaced for a new one, as far as I understand the load V is going to get determined by the drop in the Mosfet, I need 5v so maybe someone can recommend any other Mosfet with low drop?

I found this IC= [BQ24079RGTR](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/BQ24079RGTR/296-24815-2-ND/2094630), and as far as I understand it does the same function as the circuit above?

Answer (score 1):

So to cope with the voltage drop I would recommend adding a boost converter behind the MOS-FET. It will be fine if the 5V of the usb input go through it and will also improve the stability of the voltage it outputs.

For the MOS-FET you should try to get one that has pretty much the same characteristics as the one in the schematic. Most important values are the gate-source voltage Vgs and the on-resistance vs. Vgs, because if these are different the MOS-FET might not fully turn on/off.

Since I've actually taken the above [mentioned](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36930/some-advice-on-charging-circuit-used-in-simple-ups/36938#36938) circuit and improved it a little bit. You can check out the whole circuit schematic and a video about it over at [instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Raspberry-Pi-UPS/). Maybe you can reuse my circuit. Heres the schematic: [image]

Comment: I like instructables, however, now it's a linkedonly answer, so you should either elaborate about the answer/method to answer it without the link needed, or make it a comment.

Comment: If I had 50 reputation I could comment, but I think I can throw in the schematic right here. Thanks for the suggestion. I will add the schematic once I am back home.